# Example 1.4 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, elementary-set-theory

In Example 1.4 of *Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, which is showing that the $n$-sphere, $\mathbb{S}^n$ is a topological $n$-manifold, the following is stated.

In the part where the author shows that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is locally Euclidean, he does the following. For $1\leq i \leq n+1$ he let's $$U_i^+ = \{(x^1, \cdots, x^{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \ x^i > 0 \}$$ and $$U_i^{-} = \{(x^1, \cdots, x^{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \ x^i < 0 \}.$$ Then he defines $f : \mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(u) = \sqrt{1-|u|^2}$$ and claims that $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of the function $$x^i = f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1})$$ and $U_i^- \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of the function $$x^i = -f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1})$$ and where the hat indicates omission of the $x^i$.

Now here is where my confusion comes about. Let me call the first function that $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is supposedly the graph of to be $g_i$ and let me label $h_i$ as the function which $U_i^- \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of. So now $$g_i = f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1})$$ and $$h_i = -f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1}).$$ The problem that I'm having is that if I want to write down the domain and codomain of $g_i$ and $h_i$ set-theoretically, they are both going to be maps from $\mathbb{B}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$, because surely one would need both $g_i$ and $h_i$ to take inputs of the form $(x^1, \dots, x^i, \dots, x^{n+1})$ to even begin talking about removing the $x^i$, so we must have $g_i, h_i : \mathbb{B}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$, but the graph of these functions would then be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ whereas $U_i^- \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

So my question is how can we rigorously (in terms of set theory) define these functions $g_i$ and $h_i$ so that $U_i^+ \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of $g_i$ and $U_i^- \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of $h_i$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the meaning of the notation for the input parameters of $g_i$ and $h_i$. For example, consider
$$g_i = f(x^1, \dots, \widehat{x^i}, \dots, x^{n+1})
$$
What this notation means is that from the list of $n+1$ input parameters, you *remove* the $i^{\text{th}}$ parameter $x^i$, leaving you with only $n$ input parameters.

For example, if $n=4$ and $i=2$ then
$$g_2 = f(x^1,\widehat{x^2},x^3,x^4,x^5) = f(x^1,x^3,x^4,x^5)
$$

You also asked for something more rigorous from set theory, so how about this. For each $i \in \{1,...,n+1\}$ define a function $r_i : \{1,...,n\} \to \{1,...,n+1\}$ by the formula 
$$r_i(j) = \begin{cases} j &\quad\text{if $j < i$} \\ j+1 &\quad\text{if $j \ge i$}
\end{cases}
$$
Define $g_i = f \circ r_i$.

Answer (score 2):

No, $g_i$ and $h_i$ *ignore* the $i$th coordinate in the input, and is defined on $\Bbb B^n$, just as $f$. 
The two possible values for $x_i$ in the presence of the other coordinates will be obtained by $g_i$ and $h_i$.